# Swift forces me to use the self while calling the object of next class

Tags: ios, swift

I am calling the class that have, for example

```
class PreferencesCondition: BaseObject {
    var Status : Bool!
}
```

I have the object of this class in next class as:

```
var myDataSource = PreferencesCondition()
```

In this class i have many other things to do. I simply want to hide, let's say, `UIViewSecond` if **Status is true**. I am getting *true* or *false* responses from API.

So in this class I have done like this:

```
func loadData() {
    PreferencesServices.getPreferencesCondition(MemberIdProvider.sharedInstance.memberId, onCompletion: {(isSuccess: Bool, data: PreferencesCondition?) in

        if myDataSource.Status == true {
            self.UIViewSecond.hidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

This function is called in **ViewDidLoad** as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.loadData()
}
```

When I run the program to this view, it always ask me to use **self** like this

```
if self.myDataSource.Status == true
```

and the application crashes saying nil value. Nil value appears because i have use self. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: status property isn't nil ?

Comment: var Status : Bool!
 replace this with  var Status : Bool?

Comment: make sure that status property is not nil in anyway

Comment: Var status is not nil..It is true and i am getting this from API response..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you trying to access the wrong value.

```
func loadData() {
  PreferencesServices.getPreferencesCondition(MemberIdProvider.sharedInstance.memberId, onCompletion: {(isSuccess:Bool, data : PreferencesCondition?) in

     if let data = data {
       if data.Status == true {
           self.UIViewSecond.hidden = false
       }
     }
})
```

I think you want to use data, which is a variable in your closure, and not the property from the

```
var myDataSource
```

Comment: yes i was accessing the wrong value... Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding using `self.` inside your closure. From the docs

> Swift requires you to write self.someProperty or self.someMethod() (rather than just someProperty or someMethod()) whenever you refer to a member of self within a closure. This helps you remember that it’s possible to capture self by accident.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are accessing `myDataSource` inside a closure, you must use `self.` to confirm that `self` is captured.

By convention variables should start with a lower case letter, so it should be `status` not `Status`

Answer (score 0):

You are `myDataSource.Status` using it in a closure, it means the `self` is mandatory.
Your application crashes because self is deallocated when the closure is executed, so `self` is nil.

You can avoid the crash using self as a weak variable and check for it before executing the code:

```
func loadData() {
    PreferencesServices.getPreferencesCondition(MemberIdProvider.sharedInstance.memberId, onCompletion: { [weak self] (isSuccess: Bool, data: PreferencesCondition?) in

        guard let strongSelf = self else { 
            return 
        }

        if strongSelf.myDataSource.Status == true {
            strongSelf.UIViewSecond.hidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

This will fix the crash, but the logic needs to be revisited.